# php idiorm searching n database

Tags: php, database, search, orm, idiorm

Is there shorter way to do this?

```
$members = ORM::for_table('users')->raw_query('SELECT id, username, oauth_full_name, photo FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%'.$user.'%" OR oauth_full_name LIKE "%'.$user.'%"')->find_many();
    foreach($members as $member){
        echo $member->username.'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Idiorm, I use Paris more. In Paris you can do this:

```
$users = Model::factory('User')
       ->where_any_is([['username' => "%{$term}%"],
                       ['name' => "%{$term}%"],
                       ['email' => "%{$term}%"]],
                      'like')
       ->find_many();
```

Hopefully this works in Idiorm as well.